# No access stats for user after registration

Tags: users

Just noticed a new user who joined today has in access stats, "never". How can that be recording never when they have logged in? drupal 7.19 core profiles.

Comment: @saadlulu Don't forget to delete your comment as well.

Answer (score 4):

Usually a state "never" means that the user has registered but they have never logged in with their username/password

Comment: I cannot upvote your answer because the forum is having issues with logging me in, some kind of bug *not my fault* they say.